# python: using np.vectorize and np.meshgrid get a stange list of array - misunderstanding

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, mapping, numpy-slicing

I have trouble with array after using `np.vectorize` and `np.meshgrid`

Below is the result from my Terminal

[image]

**How did I get it**

```
def test_func(x, y):
    """
    some calc here:
    arr = np.linspace(1,100, num=y)
    res = another_func(x, arr) 
    return np.sum(res, axis=-1)

    """

    return # (2,2)-np.ndarray

X = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
Y = np.array([1, 2, 3])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

# res = test_func(X, Y) ---> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

func = np.vectorize(test_func, otypes=[object])

res = func(X, Y)
```

**What will be expected**

After calling the function with (x, y) get a (2, 2)-array 
After calling the function with a series (x, y) get a multidimensional -array 
slicing the result, combined with first elements in Array 
3d-plot for (x, y, result)

```
res = \
[[array([[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]),
  array([[11, 12],
         [13, 14]]),
  array([[111, 122],
         [133, 144]]),
  array([[1111, 1222],
         [1333, 1444]])],
 [array([[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]),
  array([[11, 12],
         [13, 14]]),
  array([[111, 122],
         [133, 144]]),
  array([[1111, 1222],
         [1333, 1444]])],
 [array([[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]),
  array([[11, 12],
         [13, 14]]),
  array([[111, 122],
         [133, 144]]),
  array([[1111, 1222],
         [1333, 1444]])]]

    type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    shape (3, 4)
```

After slicing get 
 
res = 
[[1 11 11 1111], 
 [1 11 11 1111], 
 [1 11 11 1111]]

then `plot_3d(X,Y,res)`

**Question**

Why the type of `res` is array? It looks like a list of array.

I tried to use
`np.array(res)`  -> change nothing, the same as the figure, shape(3, 4)

`np.array(res.tolst())` -> np.ndarray with shape (3, 4, 2, 2)

Comment: What you're defining in your question is a list of numpy arrays (with a lot of syntax errors), not a numpy array, can you provide the actual array?

Comment: @user3483203 hello, i got this array after call function func(x, y), which x,y is x,y = meshgrid(x,y), and call `type(res) = <class 'numpy.ndarray'> `.. I want to know why

Comment: you need to update your original question so we can understand what the actual value of the array is. The code you shared is not a valid piece of code to generate the array

Comment: @GerardoFlores I have updated my Question

Comment: your code is still not valid. The line X = np.array(1,2,3,4) produces an error in python 3.x, what version are you running?

Comment: @GerardoFlores Sorry..... I type it direct here. I just want to present the process, how did I get this array

Comment: You still need to add what you do inside `func`, as it might be it root of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why it does not slice?

A [`numpy.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) return a **list** of [`numpy.ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

#### Example

Suppose you want to create a meshgrid from the following `x` and `y`:

```
x = np.random.randint(10, size=(5))
y = np.random.randint(10, size=(5))
meshgrid = np.meshgrid(x,y)
```

You would get something in the likes of:

```
[array([[7, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [7, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [7, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [7, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [7, 1, 1, 0, 0]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        [7, 7, 7, 7, 7]])]
```

But that is a list, and list has no attribute shape (`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'`).

### Then how to slice this?

If you need to slice the list as a numpy matrix, convert it into a numpy array:

```
numpy_meshgrid = np.array(meshgrid)
```

Most probably the result of your `func` function also requires conversion to `numpy.ndarray`.

Now you can slice all you want:

```
array= np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 4, 2, 2))
slice = array[:,:,0,0]
```

And the result is:

```
array([[6, 7, 5, 3],
   [1, 6, 0, 5],
   [4, 5, 6, 9]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated my Question. When I use `type()`, Why do I get `type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

Comment: I have added the slicing you require.

Comment: if I use `array[:,:,0,0]` it returns `IndexError: too many indices for array`

Comment: If the function `func` returns an array with the shape `(3, 4, 2, 2)` this solution will work. If you provide `func` minimum working example we will be able to help you do so.

Comment: It's hard to give the MWE... I thougt the Problem can caused by `np.vectorize`

Comment: Without a *minimum working example* it is close to impossible to detect the issues with your code. Please try to create such a script.

Comment: I have added something, `np.array(res.tolst())` worked, get the shape (3, 4, 2, 2), but I can not explain,

Comment: Happy to hear you worked around the value returned by `func`. If my solution solved your problem, I would suggest you to edit your question so to include the actual errors of the case and mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: sincerely thanks for your help. I have rewritten my Question. Because I still don't konw why  `res` has type of `ndarray`. If I don't get a better answer, I will accept.

Comment: Well if your last operation is [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) (I'm still waiting for the full example, otherwise any assertion might be wrong) it returns a ndarray.